# What causes undefined column selected in rfe?

Tags: r

I am using the `rfe` function in the `caret` package to do feature selection. I frequently get the following error:

> 'Error in { : 
>     task 1 failed - "error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.data.frame': Error in `[.data.frame`(x, , retained, drop = FALSE) : 
>     undefined columns selected`

I'm doing 100 samples and it runs for about 60 samples or so before producing the error I'm executing the following:

```
folds=100
validmethod='boot'
subsets=c(5,10,15,20,25)

ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = funcs,
                   method = validmethod,
                   rerank=TRUE,
                   saveDetails=TRUE,
                   verbose = TRUE,
                   returnResamp = "all",
                   number=folds)

rfe(df.preds,df.depend, metric=smetric,sizes=subsets, rfeControl=ctrl)
```

Can someone help me understand the types of things which would cause this error?

MWE:

```
df <- cbind(rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), rnorm(100, 0, 1), 
    rnorm(100, 5, 5), rnorm(100, 12, 4), rnorm(100, 100, 0.1))
colnames(df) <- c("response", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4")
rfe(x=df[,-1], y=as.factor(df[,1]), sizes = 1:3,
    rfeControl = rfeControl(functions = caretFuncs, 
    number = 2, method = "cv"),method = "svmRadial")
```

How to choose `sizes`?

Comment: I'm not sure "caret" is an appropriate tag; the tag description is of the character ^, not the R package ...

Comment: Can you give us a small sample of `df.preds` and `df.depend` with `dput(df.preds)`? Even better, can you narrow it down to the data that produces the error?

Comment: In attempting to anonymize the data frame I discovered the issue has something to do with the column names. Now I have to figure out if it is special characters in the column names or if it is the length of the column names.